# How to find the maximum-weight matching

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose I have a graph with a set of edge, and a weight assigned to each edge. How can I find a maximum-weight matching of the edges? I think this is a classic CO problem but I don't know the name of the algorithm. I need this algorithm to solve an online programming puzzle.

Comment: Do you mean for graphs in general, or only for bipartite graphs?

Comment: @Mike Spivey: I am dealing with complete graphs. where every vertex could be adjacent to every other vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many books on operations research have material about matchings and weighted matchings, often only for the bipartite graph case. However, a book that treats both the general and bipartite case is Dieter Jungnickel, Graphs, Networks and Algorithms, Springer, 1999, Chapters 12 and 13.

Comment: "It would make little sense
to describe an algorithm for the weighted matching problem in general graphs
without using more of the theory of linear programming; for this reason, no
such algorithm is presented in this book."

Answer (score 2):

The name is [the Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

Comment: +1 it looks like the algorithm is suppose to find the minimum weight. I suppose if I just reverse the algorithm then I will find the maximum weight...

Comment: Negate the values, yes.

Comment: The Hungarian algorithm is for bipartite graphs.  This is not a bipartite graph.  You need Edmonds's algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27s_matching_algorithm